# CSOM - Get user permissions for root folder of a library

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I am trying to get user permissions for some folder (I don't know which one in advance) in sharepoint document library. I am using code like this:

```
var folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(relativeUrl);
context.Load(folder);
context.ExecuteQuery();
ListItem listItem = folder.ListItemAllFields;
context.Load(listItem);
context.ExecuteQuery();
var permissions = listItem.GetUserEffectivePermissions(userLoginName);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

This works for all folders except root folder of a document library. The exception says:

> Cannot enable method or retrieve property from null object. The object
> returned by the call stack below is null. ListItemAllFields

It seems like the root folder does not have a ListItem associated with it? How could I get those permissions for it then?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint library Root Folder actually return null ListItem object.

Another way to get root folder permission is to get library permission directly, this is the same as Root Folder's:

```
            Web web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
            context.Load(list);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            var permissons=list.GetUserEffectivePermissions("i:0#.f|membership|user@Tenant.onmicrosoft.com");
            context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Thank you. My problem is however that I only receive a folder url as a parameter, I don't know whether it is a root folder or not, so I don't really know which library to load

Comment: You can check the folder url format http://siteurl/LibraryName,this should be the root folder url.

Comment: I was hoping there is a better way than parsing url, but if there isn't, then that is what I will do, thanks again.